# How to change cell colour of Shiny DT table based on formula not cell value?

Tags: shiny, dt

I was wondering whether it is possible to change the colour of a DT table cell background not based on the value  of the cell but based on the difference between the cell value and another reference number provided by the user. So if the difference is < 2 cell is coloured green, if more than 2 red, etc. The idea is to be able to use some evaluation/formula rather than just the cell value.

Below is the classical example using cell value as a criteria which is not what I need.
Thank you!

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DT'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':
#> 
#>     dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  dfr <- data.frame("x"=c(1, 2, 3),
                    "y"=c(10, 12, 14))

  Reference <- 13

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(dfr) %>% formatStyle('y', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(10, 12, 14), c('gray', 'yellow', 'red'))))

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a possible solution. May need some additional tweaking to get exactly as you want but the key functionality should be there. I made use of the [formattable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html) package which you might be interested in.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
    textInput("input", "put number here"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   dfr <- data.frame("x"=c(1, 2, 3),
                     "y"=c(10, 12, 14))

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(as.datatable(formattable(dfr, list(
    y = formatter("span", 
                  style = y ~ style(
                    color = ifelse(y - as.numeric(input$input) >= 2, "green", ifelse(y - as.numeric(input$input) <= -2, "red", "black"))))
  ))))

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this would work but I was hopping there is a way to more directly do this without creating additional columns. My actual data frame can have many columns and creating addition ones is not preferable as they will need to be hidden. I looked at the example for hiding columns from the link you have provided but it just removed the column names and values not the actual column itself.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to remove the extra column. The user input is now used directly in the formatting. Does that help?